# Diferenca entre List e e Retornar em Entidade

Tags: java, sql, classes, return

Olá, estou com uma dúvida quando vou pegar os dados de uma consulta SQL, existe a possibilidade de puxar por list e por Entidade, qual é seria o "mais correto" ou a usabilidade de cada um?

```
public List<Usuario> buscarTodos(Usuario mod){...}

public Usuario pesquisarUsuario(Usuario mod) {...}
```

Comment: Acredito que seja autoexplicativo. Há vezes que você precisa buscar apenas um resultado da sua tabela `public Usuario pesquisarUsuario(Usuario mod) {...}`. E há vezes que você precisa buscar mais de um. `public List<Usuario> buscarTodos(Usuario mod){...}`

Comment: Julgo que a resposta está no nome dos métodos.

Comment: Diferenca entre List e e Retornar em Entidade !! Não seria [ Diferença entre Retornar  List ou Entidade ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

considerando as boas práticas, acredito que o primeiro método é confuso e não se aplica. Já que está passando um parametro Usuario pra listarTodos usuários, eu usaria assim:

```
public List<Usuario> buscarTodos(){...}
```

O segundo Método tem mais sentido, e por si só já é auto explicativo, ou seja, só de olhar a assinatura já se entende para o que ele serve.

```
public List<Usuario> pesquisarUsuario(Usuario mod){...}
```